# Решить нелинейное уравнение методом Ньютона

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Мне нужно найти корни уравнения в `интервале -1;3` методом **Ньютона**. Это задача из моей лабораторной работы. В ней сказано, что всего 3 корня есть. У меня есть код, который находит корень, но он один. Я не особо понимаю в матем, поэтому прошу помощи.

Функция  `x2-10·(sin(x))2+2 = 0`

Как мне найти все 3 корня? При этом необходимо сделать запрос на ввод начального приближения к тому корню, который надо получить с заданной
точностью;

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#define pi 3.14

using namespace std;

 
double f(double x) {
 
    return pow(x,2) - 10*pow(sin(x), 2) + 2;
}
 
double f1(double x) {
 
    return 2*x - 20*sin(x)*cos(x);
}
 
double f2(double x) {
 
    return   20*pow(sin(x),2)-20*pow(cos(x),2)+2;
}
 
int main() {
    int n=0;
    double a,b,c,eps;
    cout<<"a="; cin>>a;
    cout<<"b="; cin>>b;
    cout<<"eps="; cin>>eps;
    if(f(a)*f2(a)>0) c=a;
    else c=b;
    printf("    x         f(x)      f'(x)  \n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    do {
        printf("%7.4f  |  %7.3f |  %7.3f \n",c,f(c),f1(c));
        printf("-------------------------------\n");
        //cout<<c<<"\n";
        c=c-f(c)/f1(c);
        n+=1;
    }
    while (fabs(f(c))>=eps);
        cout<<"c="<<c<<"\n";
        cout<<"n="<<n<<"\n";
        getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то, четыре корня. В силу четности x^2 и (sin x)^2...

Comment: @Harry from Kiev так в условии же описано ограничение по интервалу -1;3

Comment: У вас есть уравнение, и есть одна переменная. Насколько я понимаю, корнем является такое значение `x`, при котором выполняется условие, что вот это  `x^2-10*(sin(x))^2+2` равно тому, что написано через знак `=`, в данном случае это 0. То есть нужно просто подставить все значения x в интервале -1;3. И посмотреть при каких значениях условие выполнилось.

Comment: Продолжу мысль :) Вам надо найти два корня, третий добавится просто сменой знака у одного из корней, попадающего в данный интервал.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, поскольку вообще говоря, вы не знаете, сколько корней и какие они, имеет смысл либо набросать график исходной функции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в интересующем вас диапазоне (можно только в положительной части, с учетом симметрии):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и прикинуть, где находятся корни, и соответственно выбрать нужные начальные значения для метода Ньютона, либо применить метод к разным начальным точкам и посмотреть, что получится...

```
double next_x(double x)
{
    double s = sin(x), c = cos(x);
    return x - (x*x-10*s*s+2)/(2*x-20*s*c);
}

double Solve(double start, double eps = 1e-8)
{
    double x = start, y = next_x(x);
    while(abs(x-y) > eps)
    {
        x = y;
        y = next_x(x);
    }
    return y;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(double x = 0.2; x <= 3; x += 0.2)
    {
        cout << x << "   " << Solve(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

А получится что-то вроде:

```
0.2   0.493435
0.4   0.493435
0.6   0.493435
0.8   0.493435
1   0.493435
1.2   -2.17806
1.4   -0.493435
1.6   2.17806
1.8   2.17806
2   2.17806
2.2   2.17806
2.4   2.17806
2.6   2.17806
2.8   2.17806
```

и вы видите, что в рассмотренном диапазоне [0,3] есть корни 0.493435 и 2.17806. Рассматривая симметричные корни из начального диапазона, получаем

-0.493435, 0.493435 и 2.17806

Или расширьте начальные точки на весь диапазон...

Но график лучше набросать, он подскажет, сколько корней и где примерно они находятся.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!Может подскажете еще такой вопрос: как мне сделать это " При запуске программы необходимо сделать запрос на ввод начального приближения к тому корню, который надо получить с заданной точностью;"

Comment: И может знаете как по этим корням построить график сходимости ?

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет форму принятого ответа (птичка слева). О "сделать запрос" — ну просто запрашиваете это начальное значение у пользователя, в чем вопрос? Или мне еще и сдать за вас работу преподу? :)  И - что такое "график сходимости", я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: я не понимаю для чего запрашивать начальное значение? может вы объясните ,если понимаете. нужен график сходимости Xk к указанному корню x*. А что такое Xk не пойму

Comment: Первое - видите параметр `start` в функции поиска корня? Вот это и есть начальное значение. Из разных начальных значений вы попадаете в разные корни. А второе - видимо, от вас хотят вывода промежуточных значений в цикле вычислений. Разберитесь, как работает программа, и вы поймете, как это сделать. Похоже, я и так зря так много кода написал, вызвав у вас иллюзию, что можно на шару получить готовую работу, не трудясь. Кстати, именно поэтому интеграл считать не буду и вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за вашу работу, но я заочник, и никто ничего не объясняет как делать,с программированием раньше не встречался, а тут сразу такие задачи. Я стараюсь как-то делать , но для меня это сложно самому разобраться